# Timezone attribute in PrimeFaces schedule component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

What does the timezone attribute of primefaces schedule do? I have created an event and saved it to database in UTC. If i set the timezone attribute of schedule to UTC or IST or EST it does not have any change. I think it should render the event in the specified timezone, am I correct?

Comment: Just want to know, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment, I had made some changes to the schedule.js file. This file has a varriable 'ignoreTimezone' this is set as true. so the schedule component will ignore timezone. I have made it to false. In another function which returns a date we have to calculate the date with offset , the offset part was missing.

Comment: Great, this seems to confirm what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the ignoreTimezone to false (it is true by default).

```
<p:schedule ...ignoreTimezone="false" />
```

According to [PrimeFaces documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf) : By default, timezone offsets are ignored. Set ignoreTimezone to false so that schedule takes care of timezone differences by calculating the client browser timezone and the event date so that events are displayed at the clients local time.